# IP Address to access a Docker container from a Kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am running an Oracle database as a Docker container which maps to a local port of 1521. I also have a Kafka cluster running on Kubernetes which is trying to connect to the database container. How do I get the IP of the container so that the Kafka Kubernetes pod can connect to the database? I tried 127.0.0.1 and localhost and neither did work.

Comment: One point is not clear to me... In the same K8s cluster you have both a Pod Oracle DB and a Kafka installation right? Because in this case you can take advantage of local DNS and resolve the DB with DB-SVC-NAME.NAMESPACE-NAME.svc.cluster.local.

Comment: Calling across different container environments doesn't really work well.  Can you move the database into a Kubernetes StatefulSet?  Otherwise you'd be limited to trying to make a call from the Pod to its Node's host system (and limited to a single Node), and accessing the Docker container via its published port.

Comment: No, the Oracle container is running outside of the Kubernetes cluster where the Kafka cluster is hosted/running. In other words, the database container (standalone Docker) and the Kafka cluster (on Kubernetes) are not sharing any network.